# Find index for submatrix with maximum sum

Tags: matrix, discrete-optimization

Given an N-dimensional matrix `A`, I want to find an `M<N` dimensional index array `I` such that the submatrix `A[I, I]` has the maximum element sum over all such `I` vectors.

For example for 3-dimensional

```
A = 
1  2  3
4  5  6
7  8  9
```

and 2-dimensional index `[1,3]`

```
A[(1,3), (1,3)] = 
1  3
7  9
```

So basically this is a discrete optimisation problem with N choose M possible solutions.

Is there an efficient way to find the best solution?

Comment: Are the entries in $A$ all nonnegative, or could some entries be negative?

Comment: @BrianBorchers, $A$ is a correlation matrix, so potentially [-1,1]. But most use cases for me have only nonnegative elements (or small neg numbers can be treated as 0 considering estimation error).

Answer (score 2):

This is a [binary knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_knapsack_problem) which is known to be NP-hard. No efficient algo exists yet, but there are algos that can solve problem up to size of 400 variables (according to a paper published in 1999).